# Where is the Feature Editor Template Window?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, editing

Shouldn't the feature editor window be under the 'Windows' drop-down at the top? Where is the Feature Editor Template Window?

Comment: Related/Duplicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103318/where-did-my-create-features-window-go That question is newer, but has more answers and alternative possible solutions (ie, corrupted profile). However I'm not clear if they're really duplicates, since the *Template* window as GISKid points out is one level further down than the *Create Features* window. Nor am I sure why this has so many downvotes and the other doesn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where did my Create Features window go?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103318/where-did-my-create-features-window-go)

Answer (score 3):

First enable the editing toolbar --> Customize --> Toolbars --> Editor or right click any grey area and add the editor there. 
The feature template menu can be found by entering an edit session clicking on "Create Features" (the far right menu) and then clicking the right most menu under the create features panel (see attached screenshot) [image]

Here is some additional documentation [about feature templates](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000003zm000000.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

1. Start Editing
2. In the editor toolbar: Editor > Editing Windows > Create Features

[image]

Or, the right most button on the toolbar:

[image]

Comment: It's also the rightmost button on the editing toolbar.

Comment: Post updated to address comments, thanks @Evil Genius.