# Create Features window disappeared?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, editing

I closed the window and now I can't find it again. I've tried the Editor toolbar dropdown and Create Features is not even on there (at all, not even greyed out).

Suggestions?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you use dual monitors?  I've had a similar problem before - when my window has gotten pushed almost all the way off the screen and only a small sliver remains visible.  I've also changed dual monitor settings before and had windows end up in placed that I couldn't see without changing my monitor settings back.  Just a few ideas.

Comment: The last tip with the green tick mark solve my problem. Just to the the Untility and choose the "AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe", then check "create features using templates", reopen your arcmap, then start editors, everything works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to johns and Chris W! That was it! The Advanced Arcmap Settings under the program Utilities folder was exactly the issue! After a total program reinstall, .dll inspection, and multiple (hundreds!) of button clicks, it was the simple "Create Features using templates" checkbox. Now the real question is how did that box become unchecked? If it is some kind of feature that can be messed with within the program, why does it have to be utilized through a separate .exe program?
We may never know... ;)

*here is a screen shot for future reference, along with the path listed above:
[image: Advanced Arcmap Settings program]

Path to executable AdvancedArcMapSettings:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\Utilities**

Comment: That box actually represents a Windows Registry key. It's possible that something (either in ArcGIS or another program) modified the registry directly. Third party tools can do that if they require a setting in a particular way to function. The reason they are a separate utility and not in ArcGIS is because they are registry keys, which cannot be changed from within or while their applicable program is running (hence my note about no Arc windows running). The separate .exe is just a specialized GUI that does the same thing regedit does. Also, note you can accept your own answer after 48 hours.

Answer (score 15):

There are two ways to get at the Create Features window from the Editor toolbar:

1) Start Editing.  Right-click on toolbar and select "Editor"

[image]

2) In the editor toolbar: Editor > Editing Windows > Create Features

[image]

---

Alternatively, the right most button on the editor toolbar:

[image]

Comment: I tried both of those and unfortunately they both are just not there (!). The Create Features under Editing Windows, not there, and the icon to the right of Sketch Properties icon, not there. I have already rebooted the program to no avail... tempted to reboot computer but I figured a program reboot would take care of that. (awesome visuals there btw... wish everyone answered that well!)

Comment: @MrJoshua One more thing: did you make sure that the editing session is active (e.g. editor > start editing) before you tried to access the Create Features window?

Comment: Not that it is likely given the history of merely closing the window, but the Create Features capability can be turned off.  You might see if "Create Features using templates" in the Advanced Settings Utility's Editor tab is still checked.

Comment: @johns What is the "Advanced Settings Utility's Editor" located?

Comment: This is great! I had been messing about with Add-ins and killed my mxd template.  Resetting it allowed my ArcMap to open again.  I was definitely stumped there for a bit on what to do without reinstalling!

Comment: @MrJoshua You can find the Advanced Settings editor in the C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\Utilities\ folder (or whatever similar path depending on your version and OS). It's an .exe that isn't given a shortcut on the Start menu. You shouldn't have *any* Arc windows open when launching it for proper operation.

Comment: @MrJoshua Also note that Aaron's first step begins with "Start Editing", as his comment points out. Some tools/menu options don't even display, grayed out or not, unless you are in an edit session. There are also options in various places whether to show a button on a toolbar or not - can't recall if that's one of them (it would be under Editor Options I think). But if you *are* missing buttons from toolbars, that could indicate a custom profile is loaded, yours is modified (ie you accidentally deleted the button), or your profile is corrupted as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 10):

In Windows explorer copy and paste the following location in the address bar and replace username with your username on the machine with the arcGIS install on it.:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcMap\Templates

Delete normal.mxt (your mxd template)
this will restore you mxd to it stock/original format with all your toolbars and windows where they would be when you first open the mxd.

Comment: +1 This solution is applicable not only to this question (potentially), but is great for solving pretty much any other ArcMap interface nastiness.

Comment: Unfortunately the address you gave, I'm stopped at \username\... then there is no appdata\... If I go through C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\Templates there is no "normal.mxt"       Could that be the problem?

Comment: I believe I had the same error as OP and this solved it. +1 @MrJoshua

Comment: We even have our county GIS IT guy on it and he's baffled!

Comment: you cant browse to this location for some reason, but it exists. copy and paste the above location in the address bar, in windows explorer, (and obviously replace "username" with your user name on the machine)and you should find normal.mxt.

Comment: @MrJoshua It is possible to browse to that folder, however it is a system folder. If your Explorer options are set to default, you can't see it. You need to go to Tools > Folder Options, click on the View tab, and then either uncheck "Hide protected..." and/or click the "Show hidden..." radio button under Hidden Files and Folders. If it really isn't there, then your entire Windows profile is corrupted, not just your ArcGIS profile.