# Go To XY not working in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, coordinates, xy

I found a new problem after installing ArcMap 10.3.1 in my laptop. When I clicked Go To XY, the toolbar (below) is not shown. When I clicked Go to XY, nothing happened.

How do I solve my problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Things that I would try in this order are:

- click on another button in the same toolbar, and then click this button again.  I have seen this behaviour from the Measure tool on that toolbar.
- close ArcMap (and perhaps reboot your machine) before restarting it
- locate and [re-initialize your Normal.mxt file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/103334/115)
- consider plugging in another screen to see if the toolbar has been moved off-screen
- uninstall, then reinstall, ArcGIS Desktop and bring it to the latest release at the same time, if possible

Answer (score -1):

[image: in arcgis 10.3]

In ArcGIS 10.3 you can find it when you activate the "tools" toolbar

Comment: thanks, but i have activated that toolbars, this is my screenshot. When i clicked Go to XY, no anything happened.